# I want to Iterate through an xlsx, using Pandas, containing timestamps and get downtime

Tags: python, pandas

So I have an excel file with date in the first column and a regular interval timestamps in the consecutive rows and a column in the end containing the average. If the average is below 100, I have to iterate through that specific column and find the cells with more than one consecutive zeroes as that represents the downtime.

After finding those zeroes I have to store their timestamps and the get the duration of that downtime for that date. So far I know how to iterate and find the specific row with average below zero. I am stuck at the part where I can find 2 or more consecutive zeroes and store their timestamps.

An example of the table is:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+
|  Date   | Timestamp1 | Timestamp2 | TImestamps3 | Timestamp4 | Average |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+
| 1-10-18 |        100 |        100 |           0 |        100 |      75 |
| 2-10-18 |        100 |          0 |           0 |        100 |      50 |
| 3-10-18 |        100 |          0 |           0 |          0 |      25 |
| 4-10-18 |        100 |        100 |         100 |        100 |     100 |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+
```

So now all I want to do is get this in a dictionary

```
{2-10-18:'Timestamp2-Timestamp3',3-10-18:'Timestamp2 Tmestamp4}
```

Comment: It would be better if you give a create a table of the sample xlsx file and the desired output. Also mention the approach you took in code (not text, if you can). Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for help on asking a good question.

Comment: @nishant fixed the issue, hope there is clarity now

Comment: Why is there no entry in the dictionary for `Date:1-10-18`? According to the logic, the average is `75(<100)` and you also have `Timestamps3=0`.

Comment: @nishant, the number of consecutive zeros should be more than one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moved calculation into dictionaries, as i could not find a suitable solution via Pandas.

```
  #convert to dictionary
  A = df.set_index('Date').to_dict('index')

  #remove values where 'Average' is less than 100
  B = {key:value for key,value in A.items() if value['Average'] < 100}

  #get rid of the 'Average' key
  #it is not relevant to the solution
  for value in B.values():
     del value['Average']

  from collections import Counter,defaultdict
  d=defaultdict(list)

 #count the number of 0s
 #if it is greater than one, keep
 #and append to the defaultdict d
 for key,value in B.items():
    m = Counter(value.values())
    M = list(value.values())
    #check for consecutive 0s in list
    test_for_consecutive_0 = any(i==j==0 for i,j in zip(M,M[1:]))
    if test_for_consecutive_0  and (m[0]>1):
        d[key].extend([key for key,val in value.items() if val==0])


 #join the values into a string
 result = {key:'-'.join(value) for key,value in d.items()}
 print(result)

 {'2-10-18': 'Timestamp2-TImestamps3',
  '3-10-18': 'Timestamp2-TImestamps3-Timestamp4'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, couldn't quite get the wrap around dictionary use.

Comment: the data stored in the value is in "datetime(hh,mm)" format.
I tried using the strftime function but tis not woking, i want it in HH,MM,SS

Comment: I am way beyonf that , so for some reason the compile prints it as normal time when printing through shell but when storing it in the list, it stores as "datetime.time()"I just need to figure out where to use the string conversion to convert it to string whe storing so it doesnt switch back to staetime.time

Comment: we are referring to the timestamps i believe. i guess you could go the extra mile and wrap the values in the dictionary with str() ... just clutching at straws rili. u could check the result dictionary and try the values in str. again,just a guess

Comment: Yeah thats what I am trying to do as of now

Comment: So there is a new issue I am facing.Solvedd all the previous ones, explicitly converted it to str in dict.
ok so the issue is, for example for one date if there are more than one intervals which have a downtime, its processing it as one big interval, it isnt making 2 seperate entries in the dictionary for one day, is it possible to do that?

Because when I have to calculate duration of downtime, I simply count the number of elements in the value list and do the necessary, I tried with takewhile as well, not working.I need 2 entries with the same key in one dict, is it possible.

Comment: hi @Geralt, it would be easier to create a new question for this - makes it much easier to answer and for others to butt in as well. I have lost track of the question frankly, hence the need for a new question. u can even reference the solution here

Comment: alright cool.just doing that, docheck back and answer in some time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971439/traversal-and-manipulation-of-data-in-a-dataframe

Comment: added the new question, please refer

Comment: in the variable 'test_for_consecutive_0' I want to make it into a list., use the same condition and store the column names(timestamp) of the zero values, how can I do that

Comment: u could append it as a list or assign to anoda variable. It might mean rewriting the script. not sure anymore