# Traversal and manipulation of data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So this is in reference to a previous question, an extension to that.

[I want to Iterate through an xlsx, using Pandas, containing timestamps and get downtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808781/i-want-to-iterate-through-an-xlsx-using-pandas-containing-timestamps-and-get-d/60811346?noredirect=1#comment107789909_60811346)

So I have achieved a dictionary which contains the timestamps for downtimes with the dates as their keys.
However now the issue arises that if there are two seperate downtimes in one day, instead of having a seperate entry for it, it is appended in the list of downtimes so for example it shows as

```
Timestamp('2019-10-18 00:00:00')":['00:20:00','00:30:00','00:20:00','00:40:00','05:50:00','05:60:00']
```

So to uxplain the purpose, from this entry, I extract the first and last element to get the start and end time for a downtime at any particular day and then give the total hours.

I am able to seperate them into two different dictionaries, I used this:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index')
print(df)
df1=df1.fillna('0')
df1=df1.replace(to_replace =0,value ='0')
for i in df1.index:
    print(i)
    for j in range(len(df1.loc[i])-3):
        if (df1.loc[i][j+1] is not '0' and df1.loc[i][j] is not '0'):
            #the error is faced over here is, we have a total of 72 72 rows, however not all of the are filled for all the timestamps, hence they remain as  NoneType, thus need to be ignored.
            x=(datetime.datetime.strptime(df1.loc[i][j+1],"%H:%M:%S"))-(datetime.datetime.strptime(df1.loc[i][j],"%H:%M:%S"))
            if(x>datetime.timedelta(seconds=600)):
                print(df1.loc[i][j]," ",df1.loc[i][j+1])
                print(i,"fixed")
                #this gives us the complete appended dictionary with two new entries however we are missing the Date column for these
                z=list(df1.loc[i][:j])
                y=list(df1.loc[i][j+1:])
                z={i:z}
                y={i:y}
                df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(z, orient='index')
                df3=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(y, orient='index')
                df1=df1.drop(i)
                df1 = pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=False,sort=False)
                df1 = pd.concat([df3, df1], ignore_index=False,sort=False)
                df1=df1.fillna(0)
                df1=df1.replace(to_replace ='0',value =0)
                break
        else:
            break
```

so after the processing, i was getting a dictionary stored by the name of result.
The error I am getting after this is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 85, in <module>
    x=(datetime.datetime.strptime(df1.loc[i][j+1],"%H:%M:%S"))-(datetime.datetime.strptime(df1.loc[i][j],"%H:%M:%S"))
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not int
```

As you can see, I have specified the if confition to not go beyond the elemts which are non-zero but still this error occurs.

Comment: hi Geralt, the question is not properly formatted. Kindly do that, so you can get response from SO

Comment: yes i fixed it,thanks

Comment: why is there a R tag?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your code. But put your x= in a try/expect block.